# How to have an itemized list in beamer conditionally appear

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays, pause

I would like to have an itemized list of points with follow-up points appearing once I am taking about that item. My guess is that this is going to need something like a pause, overlay, or the \only commands. Below is what I would like the slides to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}   

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<1->]
\item First.
  \only<2>{\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \end{itemize}}
\item Second.
  \only<3>{\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
  \end{itemize}}
\item Third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}   

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<1->]
\item First.
  \only<+(1)>{\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \end{itemize}}
\item Second.
  \only<+(1)>{\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
  \end{itemize}}
\item Third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]